# How to save SharedPreferences as an boolean flutter (problem)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, sharedpreferences

I try to change theme by try to use SharedPreferences to save the data. So when I reopen the app it doesn’t reset. But the problem is when I reopen the app it does reset every-time.

**Please look though my code**
and maybe point out what’s wrong or provide some code if you’ve already knows. Thanks

In theme:

```
   bool? colorMode = true;

  Future<bool> savebool(bool value) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setBool("colorMode", true);

    return colorMode!;
  }

  Future<bool> loadbool() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.getBool("colorMode")!;

    return colorMode!;
  }

        InkWell(
          child: Row(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: const [
            SizedBox(
              width: 30.0,
              height: 60.0,
            ),
            Text('- Dark Mode', style: TextStyle()),
          ]),
          onTap: () => {
            themeManager.themeMode == ThemeMode.dark,
            setState(
              () {
                themeManager.toggleTheme(colorMode!);
                colorMode = colorMode;
                savebool(colorMode!);
              },
            ),
          },
        ),
```

In main (some):

```
      ThemeManager themeManager = ThemeManager();

  @override
  void initState() {
    themeManager.addListener(themeListener);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    themeManager.removeListener(themeListener);
    super.dispose();
  }

  themeListener() {
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        Provider(create: (_) => User),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => themeManager)
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'My app',
        themeMode: themeManager.themeMode,
        theme: ThemeData.light(),
        darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
        home: const LoginScreen(),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to set `colorMode` in `loadbool()` function...

```
  Future<bool> loadbool() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    ///right here, i think it must be like this
    colorMode = prefs.getBool("colorMode") ?? false;

    return colorMode!;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your codes aren't full enough. I can't see the way you use save/load function. Anyway, before you get value from shared preference, you have to check it if it is null. I often load shared preferences in my singleton, like "isLogin", "firstOpenApp", "token"... Example:

`DataInstance().firstLogin = prefs.getBool(PreferenceConstant.PREF_KEY_FIRST_LOGIN) ?? true;`